# flash on iPad - is it possible

Tags: flash, ipad

I have to decide whether I should choose a Flash or a HTML5 presentation tier third party application for displaying virtual tours. The thing is: The Flash app is better, but doesn't work one iPad. Which do you think I should go for? Flash, high quality or HTML5, a little worst quality?

Anyway is it possible to run a Flash app on iPad, and how many people do that if possible.

Comment: Why doesn't it work on the iPad? Do you require any special Flash features that AIR for iOs doesn't support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use Adobe AIR to publish flash content to iPad/iPhone as an App.

Answer (score 0):

You could build it in flash and try out swiffy: http://swiffy.googlelabs.com/
If converts "Some" flash files, so test early and often.

My personal pref would be to build in html5 from day one, and know that it will work.

Comment: There's also Wallaby (http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/wallaby/) but I had better results with swiffy. The main limitation of swiffy is that only handles only AS2 - and ofc not completely.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could find a place that does better HTML5 tours. Or have someone make it natively, if your going to be publishing as an app anyway.